# In iOS 8 what is the correct way to add a gesture recognizer on everything in my view controller except a button, without adding an additional button?

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a button that when tapped shows the button text. In iOS 8 what is the correct way to implement a gesture recognizer to my view controller, so that when anything else is tapped besides that button will remove that text. I would like to avoid adding an additional button because I have multiple buttons that I would like to apply this gesture recognizer to in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `touchesBegan` - that would capture touches elsewhere, however if you have another UI element in the view that interacts with touch I believe `touchesBegan` will not be called in that case as the UI element will not pass the touch event on.

Implement it and pop some logging in there and see what's going on. Could be the solution you're after.

Comment: This worked well for me. I did have to set my scroll view to -->

    setUserInteractionEnabled:NO